# How to create HTTP post connection in Parallel.io Java

Tags: java, maven, parallel-processing

How to create HTTP post connection to multiple URLs and post the JSON data to get the response from all the URLs using parallel.io in JAVA. I have tried with the below code set. But getting 404/java.net.ConnectException: http error

```
public class ParallecService {

private ParallelClient parallelClient;
private List<String> postHostsList = Arrays.asList("http://www.url1.com", "http://www.url2.com", "http://www.url3.com");

public void processRequest() {
    parallelClient = new ParallelClient();
}

public void processPostRequests() {
    parallelClient = new ParallelClient();
    String requestBody = "JSON DATA";
       parallelClient.prepareHttpPost("").setConcurrency(20).setTargetHostsFromList(postHostsList).setHttpHeaders(new ParallecHeader().addPair("Content-Type", "application/json")).setHttpEntityBody(requestBody).execute(
               new ParallecResponseHandler() {

                   public void onCompleted(ResponseOnSingleTask responseOnSingleTask, Map<String, Object> map) {
                       responseOnSingleTask.getStatusCode().replaceAll("", "_");
                       System.out.println("Status Code : " + responseOnSingleTask.getStatusCode());
                       System.out.println("Last Updated" + PcDateUtils.getNowDateTimeStrStandard());
                       System.out.println(responseOnSingleTask.getErrorMessage());
                       System.out.println(responseOnSingleTask.getStackTrace());
                       System.out.println(responseOnSingleTask.getError());
                       System.out.println(responseOnSingleTask.getRequest().getRequestContent());
                   }
               }
       );
       parallelClient.releaseExternalResources();
   }
}
```

Comment: are all your URLs without any URL postfix? if so, try adding "/" to `prepareHttpPost("/")`

Comment: No. All the URLs are different from each other. No common domain and postfix URLs

Comment: ok, therefore think about what is the implication of `prepareHttpPost("")` ... Perhaps passing to it the last forward-slash is the way to work around your limitation